# XAxis label angle in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for my project.
Is it possible to rotate the labels of the XAxis by 270 degrees so that I can fit more text?

Comment: Have u implemented this xlabel rotations in bar chart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Original answer:

*Unfortunately it is currently not possible to rotate the values on the x-axis of a chart to a certain degree / angle.
You will have to implement such a feature yourself.*

**UPDATE:**

As of [v2.1.5](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases) this feature is now available:

```
 XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

do it simply by

```
    XAxis xAxis=barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-45);
```