# MPAndroidChart : Is it possible to rotate value labels for a given DataSet?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

In my Android application I have a bar chart I made using `MPAndroidChart`. My problem is when there are a number of bars in bar chart then the value labels above each bar are overlapping with other value labels as shown in the attached screen shot below. I know this is because there is no room for displaying the label, but I think this can be avoided if it is possible to rotate the value label by 90 degrees like in XAxis labels in my screen shot. So is that possible? If I zoomed then I can see all values clearly. I am using `MPAndroidChart` v3.0.1.

[image: MPAndroid Chart]

Below is my code.

```
        yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listChart.size(); i++){
        BarEntry newBEntry = new BarEntry(i,listChart.get(i).getAmount());
        xVals.add(listChart.get(i).getAltName());
        yVals1.add(newBEntry);
    }
    BarDataSet set1;
    if (bChartRepOne.getData() != null && bChartRepOne.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) bChartRepOne.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        bChartRepOne.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        bChartRepOne.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, chart);
        set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextSize(8f);

        bChartRepOne.setData(data);
    }

    XAxis xAxis = bChartRepOne.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(xList.size()-1);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            if(Math.round(value) >= xList.size()) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return xList.get(Math.round(value));
            }
        }
    });
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(-90);

    YAxis leftAxis = bChartRepOne.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    YAxis rightAxis = bChartRepOne.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

    Legend l = bChartRepOne.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);

    bChartRepOne.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry entry, Highlight highlight) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this: v2.1.5 this feature is now available: [Rotate labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754841/12427903)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.0.1 there is no method exposed to draw the value labels for a given `DataSet` on an angle. This is something you can check by using the auto-complete in your IDE when you are working on a `DataSet` object.

If you want to attempt it yourself, you will have to write a custom renderer and call:

```
mChart.setRenderer(myCustomRenderer);
```

To make the custom renderer, you would subclass [`BarChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/ccf6b7e3b1054a5a47d2822148cc19c14e9c3da6/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/BarChartRenderer.java) and override the following method:

```
drawValue(Canvas c, IValueFormatter formatter, float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color)
```

You would put there the code to render one label at an arbitrary rotation.

There is a method inside [`Utils`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/ccf6b7e3b1054a5a47d2822148cc19c14e9c3da6/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/Utils.java) called:

```
drawXAxisValue(Canvas c, String text, float x, float y,
                                  Paint paint,
                                  MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees)
```

that contains the code for drawing text at an angle so you can use that as a template.

Comment: Can u please show me how to create myCustomRenderer.Also what are the values for c,text,x,y,paint,anchor in drawXAxisValue() ??\

Comment: Is the same solution works for Horizontal bar chart.And also does this method of changing label angles cause any delay??

Comment: @KJEjava48 it's exactly the same for Horizontal bar chart or anywhere else in the library where there is no public API exposed for rotation. This or _any_ method of changing label angles will cause a small (but probably unnoticeable) performance hit.

Comment: @KJEjava48 here's an example where the questioner wrote a custom renderer by themselves. I hope it helps you. If I have time, I'll put some more details for you later about custom renderers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444573/custom-position-for-bar-values/41514885#41514885

Comment: here values of each bar's are getting overlapped,what will do if the axis labels when overlapped as here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42731804/mpandroidchart-horizontalbarchart-labels-overlapping?noredirect=1#comment72793824_42731804" .Does the same solution work for both the case??

Answer (score 1):

I rotated the values in bar chart. It may help to someone. code is

```
public class MyBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {
public MyBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
}



@Override
public void drawValue(Canvas c, IValueFormatter formatter, float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {

    // super.drawValue(c, formatter, value, entry, dataSetIndex, x, y, color);

    Paint paint=super.mDrawPaint;
    paint.setTextSize(25f);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    Utils.drawXAxisValue(c,value,x,y,paint, MPPointF.getInstance(),270);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code for custom renderer to rotate text at -60 degrees

```
public class CustomBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    public CustomBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawValue(Canvas canvas, IValueFormatter formatter, float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {
        mValuePaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(-60, x, y);

        canvas.drawText(formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler), x, y, mValuePaint);
        canvas.restore();

        /*
        Alternate solution
        Paint paint = super.mDrawPaint;
        paint.setTextSize(25f);

        //paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        //paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
        Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, value + "", x, y, paint, MPPointF.getInstance(), -60);
        */
    }

}
```

And to set renderer use :

```
barChart.setRenderer(new CustomBarChartRenderer(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler()));
```