# How to get the labels on the left side of the chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm developing an app that requires some graphs to be show for which I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). The layout requested to me was similar to the following one:

[image]

How do I set the legends ( in the image `Jun`, `May`, `Apr` ) beside the bars like the image above?

I've tried changing the `<HorizontalBarChart>.Legend.Position` but it didn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687572/show-labels-on-right-and-values-to-left-side-of-horizontal-bar-chart-mpandroidch/43737515#43737515

Answer (score 0):

The labels "Jun", "May", ... you are seeing on the left side of the chart are actually the `XAxis` of the `HorizontalBarChart`.

You can customize them by using the [ValueFormatter](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/).